# When I try to set the adaptor configuration in Wireguard Custom Client (Golang), I get the error "The parameter is incorrect." How do I resolve this?

Tags: c, windows, go, vpn, wireguard

I am trying to build a custom client using Golang for wireguard. I am able to load the wireguard.dll and also create the adaptor, but while setting the configuration, **I am getting the error "The parameter is incorrect.**" Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Here is my go struct for the configuration:-

```
// Struct for all above struct
type Config struct {
    Interface  Interface
    DemoServer Peer
    AllV4      AllowedIP
 }

// This is how i am trying the set the config:
   Config := Config{
        Interface: Interface{
            Flags:     InterfaceHasPrivateKey,
            PeerCount: 1,
        },
        DemoServer: Peer{
            Flags:           PeerHasPublicKey | PeerHasEndpoint,
            AllowedIPsCount: 1,
        },
        AllV4: AllowedIP{
            AddressFamily:2,
        },
    }
```

I have tried multiple permutations and combinations to resolve the issue, but I am not able to set the configuration of the adaptor in wireguard.

When I try to set the adaptor configuration in Wireguard Custom Client (Golang), I get the error "The parameter is incorrect." How do I resolve this?

Comment: Why are you using the `c` tag here?

Comment: WireguardNt has given an example in C, and I wanted to achieve this in Go. I reasoned that anyone from either community might be able to assist.

Comment: I am still waiting for the response. If anyone can help me,